# Excel - IF functions, <>=0?

Tags: excel

I am making a simple charges and paid ledger in Excel. I need the Balance column to return a blank cell if there is no values in the charged or paid columns. Initially my formula looked like this:

```
=IF(B7<0,(D6+B7+C7),IF(B7>=0,(D6+B7+C7)))

B9 = CHARGED
C9 = PAID
D8 = BALANCE from previous date
```

The issue I ran into was if no value was put into B9 but a value was put into C9, it would still return blank, I needed it to update the new balance. I came up with this:

```
=IF(B7<0,(D6+B7+C7),IF(B7>=0,(D6+B7+C7)))
```

This solves the problem of the balance updating if no charges were made but a payment was. However, I cannot get this formula to return blank if B or C columns are left blank.

If I didn't clarify enough please say so.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IF(ISBLANK(OR(B7,D7)), "", your formula)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
=IF(OR(B7="",C7=""),"",D6+B7+C7)
```